# What is the meaning of addEventListener()?

Tags: html, knockout.js, typescript

```
class MyController{

    public myEntities = ko.observableArray();

     constructor(modelData) {
            var me = this;
            me.onViewLoaded.addEventListener(() => {
                 me.myEntities.push(modelData);
            });
     }
```

I do not know the meaning of this line.

```
me.onViewLoaded.addEventListener(() => {me.myEntities.push(modelData);}
```

Is it means every time when my view loaded. It will push the data to myEntities?

Comment: The code you posted on its own makes little sense. That is: we can *speculate* to its purpose or workings, but there's too many things missing, most importantly where `onViewLoaded` comes from and/or what it is. Check the guidance in "[mcve]" for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Here is a quote from the MDN documentation:

> EventTarget.addEventListener() method registers the specified listener
>   on the EventTarget it's called on. The event target may be an Element
>   in a document, the Document itself, a Window, or any other object that
>   supports events (such as XMLHttpRequest).
>   To see more from this source, check out JavaScript MDN Reference on Google.

So .addEventListener is an example of a "method." This means when you attach it to an EventTarget "object" (me.onViewLoaded in this case), it executes an action on that object. The action here is to add a "listener" (as the name of the method would imply). So, what is an  event listener?

A listener will listen for some sort of action to take place, such as a click or a particular function. It looks like in your code, the action is the function of modelData being pushed to the myEntities object. So, the even listener is waiting for you to push the dataset modelData to your myEntities object. Hope this helps! If it does, remember to click the grayed out check next to my answer. If not, let me know in a comment!